# 4G Cellular Antenna

Tags: antenna, cellular, 3g

I have a [Huawei E3372H-153 USB 4G dongle](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/routers/e3372/specs/). It has two external antenna ports. What I want to know is that how can I make the full use of those two antenna ports to get the best 4G reception possible? Should I connect two separate antennas to those 2 ports? If so, how should they be related to each other (ex: alignment)? I also want to make the antenna(s) myself, so I learn. What are the factors to consider when making an antenna? (My mobile network provider uses the FDD 1800Mhz band).

I did a research on antennas in general but couldn't apply that knowledge to this specific scenario. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Link to the dongle's schematic and data sheets please. If there are none then you are asking the wrong question because nobody here is going to have access to Huawei's IP and this site does not do design questions on electrical goods that are for sale without that documentation.